# get_page_children arguments - page objects?

Tags: get-children

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children), I'm using this function to return all children from a page ID without using SQL queries.

Usage:

```
<?php get_page_children( $page_id, $pages ) ?>
```

$page is defined as a "List of pages' objects".

What are examples of page objects I would use in this case?

Comment: What are you trying achieve in the end? I assume you just want to get the children of a specific page. If yes, then there are other simple methods for it. As far as I understand the codex entry, it could be `page`, `post` or `custom_post_type`.

Comment: I thought page and post were all part of the same $post object where page would be defined as $post->post_type='page'

Comment: All of them are the same objects, if you do a `global $post; print_r($post)` on any page, you'll see it as a post object. But the type is what differentiates them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They give you an example on that page by using WP_Query to query for all pages, then `get_page_children` just filters that list. the "without using SQL queries" part is a bit of a misnomer, since you have to have already queried the database at some point to get those pages. if you don't already have a result to filter, then something like `get_children` or `get_pages` might be simpler.